# SQL Server trigger not firing when there is a character case change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm using a script to audit tables when they are updated, inserted, and deleted. I have a audit table that various information is placed in including the OLD and NEW changes if it's a update.

However if someone goes into a record and changes for example, "Help" to "HELP", my trigger is not firing. I can't seem to find in my script where I can change this behavior.

Here is my trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_addresses] 
ON [dbo].[addresses] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @bit INT ,
        @field INT ,
        @maxfield INT ,
        @char INT ,
        @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
        @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
        @PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
        @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
        @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
        @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
        @Type CHAR(1) ,
        @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000)

--You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited
SELECT @TableName = 'addresses'

-- date and user
SELECT @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
        @UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
                + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

-- Action
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
                SELECT @Type = 'U'
        ELSE
                SELECT @Type = 'I'
        ELSE
                SELECT @Type = 'D'

-- get list of columns
SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
                + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,

                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
        WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
        AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary key select for insert
SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
        + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME 
        + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
        coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
        WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
        AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
        RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
        RETURN
END

SELECT         @field = 0, 
        @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
        SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
        SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
        SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
        SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
        IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 OR @Type IN ('I','D')
        BEGIN
                SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                        AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
                SELECT @sql = '
insert Audit (  Type, 
                TableName, 
                PK, 
                FieldName, 
                OldValue, 
                NewValue, 
                UpdateDate, 
                UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
        + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
        + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
        + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
        + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
        + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
        + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
        + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
        + @PKCols
        + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
        + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is not null)' 
        + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is null)' 
                EXEC (@sql)
        END
END
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: The comparison inside the generated SQL: `where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname ` is subject to the collation defined for the columns (database). The default in SQL Server is to use case-insensitive comparison. You need to change the collation of the database (or tables, columns). But that might change the behavior of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`COLLATE` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) to force a particular comparison to use a case sensitive collation. Most of the time, the default collation is case insensitive, and so the two words are considered to be the same. Something like:

```
SELECT @sql = '
insert Audit (  Type, 
            TableName, 
            PK, 
            FieldName, 
            OldValue, 
            NewValue, 
            UpdateDate, 
            UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
    + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
    + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
    + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
    + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
    + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
    + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
    + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
    + @PKCols
    + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname
    --New line here - applies the specific collation to
    --the previous comparison operation
    + ' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS '
    + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is not null)' 
    + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is null)'
```

Whether `Latin1_General_CS_AS` is the right collation for you to use is a matter for you to decide - generally, find whatever collation is being used for those columns and then replace the `CI` part with `CS`, to get the Case Sensitive equivalent.